# Problems with finding the Longest Common Sequence of numbers of two arrays

Tags: c, lcs

This my Dynamic Programming code in C, but I do not understand why I am getting an output of `1` in place of `3`.

Also can someone suggest how I should move forward with printing the longest sequence after I have found the longest seq length?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int max(int nmu1, int num2);
int findMaxLength(int a[], int b[], int n, int m);

int main() {
    int a[] = { 1, 2, 8, 2, 1 };
    int b[] = { 8, 2, 1, 4, 7 };

    int n = sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0]);
    int m = sizeof(b) / sizeof(b[0]);

    printf("%d", findMaxLength(a, b, n, m));
}

int findMaxLength(int a[], int b[], int n, int m) {
    int dp[n + 1][m + 1];

    for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j <= m; j++)
            dp[i][j] = 0;

    for (int i = n - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        for (int j = 0; j >= 0; j--) {
            if (a[i] == b[j])
                dp[i][j] = dp[i + 1][j + 1] + 1;
        }
    }

    int maxm = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
            maxm = max(maxm, dp[i][j]);
        }
    }

    return maxm;
}

int max(int num1, int num2) {
    return (num1 > num2) ? num1 : num2;
}
```

Comment: 'I do not why I am getting an output of 1 in place of 3' - debugger, single step, inspect vars, keep notes, fix bug.

Comment: Yes I am doing that but I am still unable to catch the error. Please mind my naive nature, I am new to C and I am unable to get the debugger to run in VS

Comment: 'I am unable to get the debugger to run in VS' - that should be your question title.  If you cannot debug, you cannot program computers. Get all your tools ready before starting a job:)

Comment: Got the VS code debugger running. I fixed the error. I am getting 3 now. Can you recommend how I can go about printing the seq now?

Comment: Please do not update the question with corrected code: it makes the comments and answers inconsistent. If you want to add extra remarks or questions, append an EDIT paragraph.

Comment: Understood. Thank you! I will keep it in mind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The inner loop `for (int j = 0; j >= 0; j--)` does nothing. You should instead write:

```
for (int j = m - 1; j >= 0; j--)
```

To display the actual substring, the function `findMaxLength` must keep track of the offsets of the best match as it finds a new one. You cannot use `maxm = max(maxm, dp[i][j]);` for this, you must use an explicit test.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int findMaxLength(const int a[], const int b[], int n, int m) {
    int dp[n + 1][m + 1];

    for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j <= m; j++)
            dp[i][j] = 0;
    }
    for (int i = n - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        for (int j = m - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
            if (a[i] == b[j])
                dp[i][j] = dp[i + 1][j + 1] + 1;
        }
    }

    int maxi = 0, maxj = 0, maxm = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
            if (maxm < dp[i][j]) {
                maxm = dp[i][j];
                maxi = i;
                maxj = j;
            }
        }
    }

    if (maxm > 0) {
        printf("a[%d..%d] == b[%d..%d] == [ %d",
               maxi, maxi + maxm - 1, maxj, maxj + maxm - 1, a[maxi]);
        for (int i = 1; i < maxm; i++) {
            printf(", %d", a[maxi + i]);
        }
        printf(" ]\n");
    }
    return maxm;
}

int main() {
    int a[] = { 1, 2, 8, 2, 1 };
    int b[] = { 8, 2, 1, 4, 7 };
    int na = sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0]);
    int nb = sizeof(b) / sizeof(b[0]);
    int len = findMaxLength(a, b, na, nb);
    printf("%d\n", len);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
a[2..4] == b[0..2] == [ 8, 2, 1 ]
3
```

Note that `findMaxLength` uses at most 2 arrays at a time, so if you combine the 3 loops into one, you can reduce the size requirements from **O(n.m)** to **O(m)**:

```
int findMaxLength(const int a[], const int b[], int n, int m) {
    int dp[2][m + 1];
    int maxi = 0, maxj = 0, maxm = 0;

    for (int j = 0; j <= m; j++) {
        dp[0][j] = 0;
    }
    dp[1][m] = 0;

    for (int i = n - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        for (int j = m - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
            dp[1][j] = (a[i] == b[j]) * (dp[0][j + 1] + 1);
            if (maxm <= dp[1][j]) {
                maxm = dp[1][j];
                maxi = i;
                maxj = j;
            }
        }
        if (i-- == 0)
            break;
        for (int j = m - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
            dp[0][j] = (a[i] == b[j]) * (dp[1][j + 1] + 1);
            if (maxm <= dp[0][j]) {
                maxm = dp[0][j];
                maxi = i;
                maxj = j;
            }
        }
    }
    if (maxm > 0) {
        printf("a[%d..%d] == b[%d..%d] == [", maxi, maxi + maxm - 1, maxj, maxj + maxm - 1);
        for (int i = 0; i < maxm; i++) {
            printf(" %d", a[maxi + i]);
        }
        printf(" ]\n");
    }
    return maxm;
}
```

`(a[i] == b[j]) * (dp[0][j + 1] + 1)` computes the value of `dp[1][j]` with branchless code, which is more efficient than your `if` statement.

With this alternative, I get a **10x** performance improvement for larger array sizes, such as 16K numbers, but still suffer **O(n.m)** time complexity. More advanced algorithms are required to reduce the complexity of this classic [Longest common substring problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_substring_problem).

Comment: yes I figured that out! Thank you for your help!

Comment: Thank you. to take this further.. if I want to also print the corresponding  longest seq. how can I achieve that? I have figure out which is the corresponding array location where the seq starts then I can use the seq length to print them.

Comment: Thank you for this. Why are asking for maxi and maxj as parameters, if I didnt know any better we can still achieve the same result without passing them? Because I am bound by the pre-made function (cant use any other parameter) of the platform I am trying to submit this code to.

Comment: I am getting a weird output: 5, 0, 1893073084, -1502280889. I have updated my code in the question

Comment: @AGsims: You forgot the test `if (maxm < dp[i][j])` in the last loop. I updated the answer.